# Why does this work? Clearing a javascript object being used as a form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Take this javascript object:

```
dog = {
   owner: 'mike'
   food: 'kibbles'
   breed: {color: 'brown'
           type: 'corgie'
           gender:'f'  
          }
   neuter:'y'
   spay:'no'
   name:'Sparky'
}
```

I submit this data, and then I want to clear it on success.
if I write:

```
dog = {};
```

Nothing happens to the fields.

However, if I change the whole object to:

```
dog.info = {
   owner: 'mike'
   food: 'kibbles'
   breed: {color: 'brown'
           type: 'corgie'
           gender:'f'  
          }
   neuter:'y'
   spay:'no'
   name:'Sparky'
}
```

And then I clear the object by re-initializing the object:

dog.info = {};

It works.
I am using this to clear an angular form from inside of a service.
Does anyone know why that is the case? Your help is much appreciated as always.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you verify your typo on first block ? dog{ @Mee

Comment: dog{} means nothing in javascript, it should be like dog = {};

Comment: What is the lexical scope of `dog` variable. Can you show the code in context?

Comment: Sounds like a `$scope` issue... since `$scope.dog` is a primitive and will create a new scope if it doesn't exist... `$scope.dog.info` will look up as far as it needs.

Comment: try using `controllerAs` syntax so you can fix the scoping issue

Comment: can you provide sample html?

Comment: I seem to get it now...I wish I knew why this is down-voted though? Maybe if I knew I could edit the question.

Comment: It was likely due to the invalid syntax your code originally had, that or the lack of a usage example.

Comment: ok got it. I will be more complete next time. However, you were able to answer the question and helped me understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends very much on how exactly you are using `dog`, and since you didn't provide that, i'll make up my own example.

This has to do with the way objects are stored in variables. Take the following example:

```
var dog = {name: 'bob'};
var x = dog;
console.log(x.name); // 'bob'
x.name = 'george';
console.log(x.name); // 'george'
console.log(dog.name); // 'george'
dog = {name: 'frank'}; // dog and x now hold two different objects!
console.log(x.name); // 'george'
console.log(dog.name); // 'frank'
```

When I set `x` equal to `dog`, `x` stored the same object as `dog`, so when I modified it, `dog` was modified too. However, when I overwrote `dog` with a new object, `x` still contained the old object rather than also being updated to the new one.

By using `dog.info` and never overriding `dog`, you preserved the original object so everything is still referencing the object that is getting updated.

```
var dog = {info: {name: 'bob'}};
var x = dog;
console.log(x.info.name); // 'bob'
x.info.name = 'george';
console.log(x.info.name); // 'george'
console.log(dog.info.name); // 'george'
dog.info = {name: 'frank'}; // dog and x still hold the same object.
console.log(x.info.name); // 'frank'
console.log(dog.info.name); // 'frank'
```

Comment: Nice...I appreciate you taking the time Kevin.